# Apache2 VirtualDocumentRoot wildcard subdomains with fallback

Tags: apache-2.2

Configuring a local development linux box I'd like to have some sneaky Apache2 configuration which would do the following, when I request 'sub.domain.tld.local':

```
1.) Serve from: vhost/domain.tld/sub/htdocs/
2.) If there's no such directory, serve from: vhost/sub.domain.tld/htdocs/
3.) If there's no such directory, serve from: vhost/domain.tld/htdocs/
```

'.local' is just a static "suffix" which should not match any directory.

My current configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.local
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/vagrant/host/%-2+/htdocs/"
    VirtualScriptAlias "/vagrant/host/%-2+/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works well for 2) or 3) but not in the manner of "crawling" the directory structure and falling back from 1) to 2) to 3). Preferably I'd like to only use the VirtualDocumentRoot directive somehow without any rewrite rules.

If it won't work without rewrites, I'm of course okay with that too.

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I could make this work with a few `RewriteRule` directives (I do something similar on my servers) but I don't know hiw it can be done with just `VirtualDocumentRoot`

Comment: Seems not doable with VirtualDocumentRoot alone, because it doesn't check existence of directories. What helps a little, and what I find quite interesting, is the fact, that ServerAlias works with multiple wildcards - like: "ServerAlias \*.\*.\*.com" for example. :)